# intro.js : {done,prev,next} buttons order change to [prev,next,done]?

Tags: intro.js

now: [done,prev,next]

I want an order like [ prev,next,done ],but I have not found any Options to change the button order.
http://introjs.com/docs/intro/options/#options

there is an option about button: showButtons, but it is not about button orders.

Answer (score 1):

A few years later, but...

Now you can edit only the 'done' button and keep the 'skip' as it is:

```
.introjs-donebutton {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (tested on introjs 2.4.0):

```
.introjs-skipbutton {
    margin-left: 1em; /* adjust so button doesn't touch prev/next */
    float: right;
}
```